# Do I need to sanitize ruby file path created by input file tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that allows a user to choose a file using an input of type file:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
```

When the form posts it posts these parameters:

```
 "file"=>
  #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003e44cd0
   @content_type="application/octet-stream",
   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"invalid-test\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n",
   @original_filename="invalid-test",
   @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20171006-26097-17004vm>>
```

My program then copies the temporary file and creates a copy in a folder within the application.  The copied file is formatted to be used by another process.  This processing all works fine.  The code doing this is as follows

```
# The @myfile filename (excluding the path) has been sanitised earlier in the process.
temporary_file = params[:file].tempfile.path
input_file     = Rails.root.to_s + "/some_path/" + @myfile.filename
FileUtils.cp temporary_file, input_file
```

Having run a brakeman scan against the application it's flagging up all the places where I have used the @tempfile.path as a security risk.  I've read up on the risks in the rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection-and-files

Which say filenames should be sanitised.  I am using a sanitiser on the @original_filename to ensure that it's safe, as per the guide.  I don't think I need to do anything with the path.  The file params does not specify the path, only the filename or path and filename.  I could create the path and filename by using

```
params[:file].tempfile.path - params[:file].tempfile.original_filename
```

The create the file and path name using the calculation plus the sanitised filename.

I am not convinced that it is a problem because the application is simply taking the temporary file and taking a copy.  All future processing is then done on that file.  The filename it uses will be sanitised and the path is set by the application for future processing.  Worst case scenario would be that my process copied the wrong file.

To cut a long story short do I need to be worried about trying to sanitise the path as well as the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to sanitize the path. When the browser submits the form with the file input tag, it will fire a multipart form request that looks like this: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Notice that the multipart data only specifies a `filename`.

Web servers only receive the filename from the multipart-form POST request that the file came from. The path the temp file is saved to is configurable via the server or language config. Sanitizing the filename is all that is needed it is user input.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this and for the link Diego.  I kind of suspected that it was going to be a no.